# WooCommerce Checkout trim

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im running a web shop based on WP and WooCommerce. After the latest WC update some things changed on my checkout page and I'm looking for a way to trim the page a bit.

What I'm looking to do is to remove some of the unnecessary options shown to customers. I'm just not quite sure how do this :)?

What i want to hide/remove is:

(1) Since i only sell to Denmark
Land *
Danmark

(2) The second input box for address. Only the first is needed.
Adresse*
Apartment, suite etc.

(3) Additional information section - I dont need to have this either.
YDERLIGERE INFORMATION
Ordre Bemærkninger

I really hope that someone out there will be able to answer this and help me out! :)

The website is www.motorcykelgrej.dk <- to access the checkout page you need to add something to the basket first.

Best regards
Michael

Comment: Please see this screenshot. The red labels are around the stuff I would like to remove.
https://motorcykelgrej.dk/wp-content/uploads/wc-trim.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your theme functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    return $fields;
}
```

And this custom CSS code:

```
.checkout-group h3 {
    display:none;
}
```